# Objective-C syntax checker

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, gcc, xcodebuild

Is there an Objective-C syntax checker?

I have tried `gcc -fsyntax-only` but it is not really 'syntax only'.  It still produces errors if run on an individual implementation file which has references to external frameworks.

I am looking for something that can perform a syntax check on individual header or implementation files without attempting to link or produce object files.

Can `gcc` do this with additional flags I am unaware of, or is there another tool up to this task?

I want to do this from the command-line.  Can xcodebuild do this for an individual file?  Running xcodebuild for the entire project to check the syntax of one file is a bit much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trawling through the `gcc` man page I discovered the `-F` flag which lets you add a framework directory to the list of directories `gcc` searches for header files.

This solves my issue.

Use it like this: `gcc -fsyntax-only -ObjC -F/Path/To/A/Framework -F/Path/To/Another/Framework File.m`

Answer (score 3):

There's no way for it to check the syntax without it knowing about the header files for the frameworks you are using.  You need to use the -framework flag to include the relevant header files.

Comment: I think you mean -iframework instead. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Darwin-Options.html#index-iframework-1169

Answer (score 1):

You could try using clang -fsyntax-only instead, especially if you're using 10.6/Xcode 3.2.  Clang/LLVM has much better separation between the parser and the other parts of the compiler chain.  You can find clang in /Developer/usr/bin.

Comment: Clang reports the same errors I had with gcc.  I just want it to check the syntax, I don't want it to complain because it can't find the framework I have included in my header file.

Comment: Your problem is that the framework contains headers you need and in any C-derived language you have to have the data from the header in order to fully check the syntax.  Otherwise you'd be lacking macro definitions, type definitions and other things that contribute to the correctness of the syntax of a given compilation unit.  I would try either adding -framework options or using -I to pull in the Headers directory of the framework, eg

    -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers

for the Foundation framework)

Answer (score 0):

You can compile a single file in Xcode[1] using Build->Compile (cmd-K) which is effectively a syntax check (there's no linking step).

[1] I assume you're using Xcode, as there's little point in using Objective-C without OS X (really the Cocoa frameworks).

Comment: I want to do this from the command-line.  Can xcodebuild do this for an individual file?  Running xcodebuild for the entire project to check the syntax of one file is a bit much.  I have amended my original question accordingly.

Comment: As Benno mentions, clang may be helpful, but I'm not sure. I don't know if the compilation step only can be invoked via xcodebuild.

Comment: He speficically asked for a syntax-only check without producing or linking object files. While your solution doesn't link, it does produce object files. Stephen's answer however is *almost* correct (should use -iframework instead of -framework).